# Simplify httpd.conf file

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

Any suggestions on how to simplify my httpd.conf file?  I've stripped out everything but the relevant portions:

```
Listen <ip-addr-1>:80
Listen <ip-addr-1>:443

<VirtualHost <ip-addr-1>:80>
ServerName myservername.com

<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
BalancerMember http://172.22.22.20
BalancerMember http://172.22.22.21
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /app1 balancer://mycluster/app1
ProxyPassReverse /app1 balancer://mycluster/app1
</VirtualHost>

# Repeat for 443
<VirtualHost <ip-addr-1>:443>
ServerName myservername.com

SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile      conf/ssl/mycert.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile   conf/ssl/mycert.key
SSLCACertificateFile    conf/ssl/intermediate.crt

<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
BalancerMember http://172.22.22.20
BalancerMember http://172.22.22.21
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /app1 balancer://mycluster/app1
ProxyPassReverse /app1 balancer://mycluster/app1
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there anyway to not repeat everything for port 80 and 443, but turn on ssl for 443?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an include if you're concerned about the editability - just move the repeated part to a separate file, say `balancer.cfg` and then `Include balancer.cfg`.

If your aim is to have a single Virtual Host definition I reckon that's not possible in this case. If you had multiple ports speaking HTTP you could just use `VirtualHost 10.1.2.3:*` and it would match every port, or use a list like `VirtualHost  10.1.2.3:80 10.1.2.3:81` and so on. But in this case I don't see a way to serve both HTTP and HTTPS using the same definition - only one can match, it would seem, so the one being matched should contain the complete configuration.

> Apache selects the best match only on
>   the basis of the IP address (or
>   wildcard) and port number. If there
>   are multiple identical best matches,
>   the first VirtualHost appearing in the
>   configuration file will be selected.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/details.html

Comment: Thank you.  Includes should work pretty well for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can do a touch better:

```
Listen 80
Listen 443

ServerName myservername.com
ProxyPass /app1 balancer://mycluster/app1
ProxyPassReverse /app1 balancer://mycluster/app1

SSLCertificateFile      conf/ssl/mycert.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile   conf/ssl/mycert.key
SSLCACertificateFile    conf/ssl/intermediate.crt

<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    BalancerMember http://172.22.22.20
    BalancerMember http://172.22.22.21
</Proxy>

<VirtualHost *:80>
</VirtualHost>

# Repeat for 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

I confess that I don't know whether the VirtualHost directive for *:80 can be entirely omitted, but based on the Apache docs, this much should work.